# Login user for a custom user model with email as username field

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-login

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have implemented a custom user model by extending the `AbstractBaseUser`, now I need to get the user login to the site.

Here's what I have tried so far.

**From `models.py`:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    contenst = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = UserManager()
```

**From `urls.py`:**

```
path('login', views.UserLogin.as_view(), name='login'),
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
class UserLogin(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *ars, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': LoginForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
        else:
            return 'Something wrong'
```

**From `forms.py`:**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

when I try to log in a user, it gives an error as:

> Exception Value:  'str' object has no attribute 'get'
>
> **Update: Full Traceback:**

```
[09/Dec/2019 01:36:20] "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 5124
Internal Server Error: /user/login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
[09/Dec/2019 01:36:22] "POST /user/login HTTP/1.1" 500 54537
```

what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback as well?

Comment: added in the question.

Comment: I think it's because the `return 'Something wrong'` in the `post` method. try returning an HttpResponse (or subclass) and see it that solves the issue.

Comment: yup, now it's returning 'something wrong` after placing it in `HttpResponse` how can I get the error OR what can be wrong here?

Comment: There is no need to add a `Meta` class to your form; as you are using `forms.Form`. I think that's the issue here.

Comment: it's giving the `KeyError` for `'password'`

Comment: and the final problem is that, `PasswordInput` is a **widget**; you should use `password = forms.CharField(strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of *little* issues here:

first, you are returning a *raw* string from the `post` method; You can fix that by using:

```
return HttpResponse('Something wrong')
```

next, you have included a `Meta` class in your `LoginForm`, which is not needed in case you are using `forms.Form`.

and finally, for your `password` field in the `LoginForm`, you are using `PasswordInput`, which is a **widget** (not a form control); you can fix that by using:

```
password = forms.CharField(strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: can yo take a look at this related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59246647/7644562

Answer (score 1):

It's because for some reason your form is **invalid**, try something like that to debug the error:

```
if form.is_valid():
    ****   
else:
    print(form.errors)  # To see the form errors in the console.
```

Comment: can yo take a look at this related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59246647/7644562