# Python - Django signup for custom user model with multiple types of users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have created multiple types of users with a custom user model by extending the `AbstractBaseUser` model. I have done with the login but I'm confused about how should I implement the signup page as there's multiple types of users and I need a different form for each type of user.

Here's How I have implemented my models.

**From `models.py`:**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


CHOICES = [
    ('M', 'male'),
    ('F', 'female')
]

USER_TYPE = [
    ('PB', 'PersonalBelow18'),
    ('PA', 'PersonalAbove18'),
    ('Parent', 'Parent'),
    ('GC', 'GroupContact'),
]


def generate_cid():
    cid = "".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(8)])
    return cid


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=USER_TYPE, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    contenst = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)


class PersonalBelow18(User):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)


class PersonalAbove18(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    contact_no = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the"
                                                                  "format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    contact_no = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the"
                                                                  "format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)


class GroupContactPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    contact_no = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the"
                                                                  "format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

**What do I want? (the UI perspective):**
 I want to show the type-specific form to the user,  thinking to show all the forms on a single page in different tabs, so the user can click on the tab for which he wants to create an account and then I want to show all the fields from `User` & `PersonalBelow18`.

How can I implement signup forms & views for these multiple types of users?

Comment: Why is `PersonalBelow18` a subclass of `User` rather than a 1-to-1 relationship like the others? How to implement is a broad question, as it also depends on what your signup flow is. Please explain from a UI perspective how a user is going to signup. Are they first ask what type they are? Then fill in all the details? Or do they first fill in the general stuff + what type and then you request the other information?

Comment: @dirkgroten I was testing the signup for `PersonalBelow18`, that why just change it like that.

Comment: @dirkgroten update the question, take a look, please!

Comment: Since you're going to show forms for various models, the easiest thing is to write a function-based view (don't try to use a generic CBV for this). In the view, you initialise 5 `ModelForm`s (one for `User` and one for each of the possible profiles). After validating the `User` form you check the value chosen for user type and then validate the corresponding profile form. You might use some javascript to populate the chosen type based on the tab that was selected. Make sure you wrap everything in just one <form> tag, so everything gets submitted at once.

Comment: Oh for the `User` form you should probably subclass `UserCreationForm` (built-in in Django) that will handle user creation correctly.

Comment: @dirkgroten how should I put the forms on front-end in templates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203919/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: @dirkgroten take a look at this question, please!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59279809/7644562