# Django - get user id after saving the user

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have implemented models for multiple type of users and combined models by using `MultiModleForm` to display as a single form on front end, after that when I try to create a user in view and call the save method for `user` model and try to get its `id` but it's giving an error.

Here's what I have tried so far:

From `models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=USER_TYPE, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    contenst = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)

class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    contact_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='Phone number must be entered in the'
                                                        'format: \'+999999999\'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
```

**From `forms.py`:**

```
class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('contact_email', 'contact_no', 'collection_use_personal_data')


class UserParentForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user': UserForm,
        'profile': ParentForm
    }
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.POST)
    user_type = request.POST.copy()['user-user_type']
    form = None
    if user_type == 'PB':
        form = UserBelow18Form(request.POST)
    elif user_type == 'PA':
        form = UserAbove18Form(request.POST)
    elif user_type == 'Parent':
        form = UserParentForm(request.POST)
        print('user-parent form selected')
    elif user_type == 'GC':
        form = UserGCForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = form['user']
        profile = form['profile']
        if user_type == 'Parent' or user_type == 'GC':
            c_id = generate_cid()
            profile.customer_id = c_id
            print('id generated for parent or GC: {}'.format(c_id))

            try:
                user.save()
                profile.user = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
                # print(user_obj.email)
                # profile.user = user_obj.id
                profile.save()
                print(user.email)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('users:login'))
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse('something as: {}'.format(e))
```

But I'm getting the error as:

> something as: 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: no, I need `user.id` the actual id of the user object to pass in `profile`.

Comment: You can see in `views` I'm trying to get the id for the user which is saved right above, so it's not in the `request` at this moment, according to my understanding after calling the `save` for user it should provide the `id` even the user is created in the database with an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiModelForm` isn't part of Django and you didn't post a link to whatever project provides this class, but obviously here:

```
user = form['user']
```

`user` is the `UserForm` instance, NOT the `User` model instance. What you want is something like:

```
    # good naming is key to readable code...
    user_form = form['user']
    profile_form = form['profile']

    if user_type == 'Parent' or user_type == 'GC':
        c_id = generate_cid()
        user = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.customer_id = c_id
        profile.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('users:login'))
```

Also note that I removed your try/except clause which was worse than useless - in your dev environment you want to let Django catch those errors and render the much more useful debug page (which has the full traceback etc), and on production you want to let Django catch those errors and return a 500 response - both thing Django does by default if you don't interfere. As a general rule, if you cannot effectively handle an exception, let it propagate (and no, returning a 200 response when the request actually failed - and possibly leaking some internal informations - doesn't qualify as "effective handling").

Comment: here's the `MultiModelForm`

Answer (score 2):

The below worked for me:

```
$ python manage.py shell
...
...

>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user("test", password="test")
>>> user
<User: test>
>>> user.id 
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`user.save()` will return instance of the user object. you can use it to fetch `id`

Comment: I'm using that but it's giving the error and that's the question.

Comment: try doing:


`u = user.save()`
`profile.user = User.objects.get(id=u.id)`

Comment: another error comes as `NOT NULL constraint failed: users_parent.user_id`

Comment: I don't see any `users_parent` instance in the above code. This might be coming from the model where you have added `user_id` with constraint `null=false` or not mentioning `null` at all.

Comment: I have added the `User` model above, take a look, please!

Comment: `new_user = user.save()`
`profile.user = new_user`
`new_user_profile = profile.save()`

use instance variables to access model attributes like email, title, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204033/discussion-between-suyash-and-abdul-rehman).